# Must be array type but resolved to vector

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I get this error when trying to use vectors in my code - must be array type but resolved to Vector. 
I'm trying to split a string into two arrays, and these arrays should hold infinite locations. I've tried

```
student.addAll(Arrays.asList(student));
```

but that gives me null values when printed.

```
Vector <String> student = new Vector<>(50);
            ...                     
String Tokens[] = b.split(" ");
student[i]=Tokens[0];    // the error is here
```

Comment: You should use ArrayList instead of Vector (it's considered a legacy class) and also (in general) specify the type in the instantiation: `= new Vector<String>(50)`.

Comment: Yes I know but as part of my course we are going through vectors

Comment: add your full code please.

Comment: I know using `String student[] = new String [5];` will accept user input 5 times, but how do you accept more than 5 times using vectors? Sorry i'm a terrible beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot access Vector items by the angle brackets syntax. That is only supported for arrays in Java**.

Use `student.add(Tokens[0])` instead.